# Upper bound for the sum of non-integer powers

Tags: inequality, summation, power-series

Let $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k$ be a  positive integers such that $a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k = K$.
Is it possible to find an upper bound such that $$a_1^p + a_2^p + \cdots+ a_k^p \le f(K)$$ where $0 < p < 1$, and $f$ is some function? It is easy to see that $a_1^p + a_2^p + \cdots + a_k^p \le K$, but can I get anything better than this? I would appreciate any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $K$ and arbitrary $k$ there is no better bound because we can choose $k=K$ and all $a_j$ equal to one.

For fixed $K$ and fixed $k$ we can apply Jensen's inequality to the concave function $t \mapsto t^p$. This gives 
$$
 \left( \frac K k \right)^p =  \left( \frac{a_1 + \ldots + a_k}{k} \right)^p 
\ge \frac{a_1^p + \ldots + a_k^p}{k}
$$
so that
$$
a_1^p + \ldots + a_k^p \le k^{1-p} K^p \, .
$$
If $K$ is an integral multiple of $k$ then the bound is sharp, as can be seen by choosing all $a_j$ equal to $K/k$.

Comment: Thank you! $K$ and $k$ are fixed in my case, so your answer is very helpful.